# Android NoSuchMethodError: setForceShowIcon in PopupMenu

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, nosuchmethoderror, popupmenu, android-9.0-pie

I'm encountering a **NoSuchMethodError** in my Android application related to the **setForceShowIcon** method in the **PopupMenu** class. The error message indicates that the method doesn't exist, despite being called in my code. #This issue occurs when I try to open an existing feature in my application.#

Here are some details about my setup:

1. Android Version: 9
2. Phone Model: Nokia C2
3. TraceDroid Version: 4.1

I've already checked my dependencies and ensured they are up-to-date. Additionally, I've verified that my targetSdkVersion in the build.gradle file is set appropriately. However, the error persists.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!